# Azure Auto Scale - Last minute alone rule?

Tags: azure, automation, autoscaling

How can I create a rule that would trigger when the CPU % for the LAST minute is bigger than 90%?

Answer (score 0):

For now, we **can't** create a rule for every minute.

By default, the windows time default value is 5 mins, and this windows time **must be between five minutes and one day**.